# Shapely removing disconnected geometries after a unary_union of two MultiPolygons

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, shapely

**edit: The geometries were not dissapearing, they were in the interiors property of the Polygon.**

I have two MultiPolygons, both of which are made up of disconnected polygons. I need to join them such that they "cut" each other out. The two shapes are these;
[image]

[image]

I perform a unary union to get the shape below;
[image]

This removes the "z" shaped wall in the bottom room, which I still need. Is there a way of "cutting" shape 1 with shape 2 such that the "z" shaped room remains? The closest I've got is with unary_union and playing around with the width of the small rectangles, but this is leaving a line between the doors which is not ideal.[image]

I've tried using symetric_difference, but this also did not work.

```
un_rm = unary_union(rooms)
un_dr = unary_union(doors)

# plot_multipoly(un_rm, plt)
# plot_multipoly(un_dr, plt)

# nonoverlap = (un_rm.symmetric_difference(un_dr))
un = unary_union([un_rm, un_dr])
```

Here's the geometries for the rooms

```
POLYGON ((85887.4870641205488937 -25151.4419914101599716, 64629.2000917164332350 -25151.4419914101599716, 65757.5078179416013882 -28251.4419914100362803, 79287.4870641207526205 -28251.4419914100362803, 85887.4870641205488937 -28251.4419914100362803, 85887.4870641205488937 -25151.4419914101599716))
POLYGON ((64416.3645372212558868 -25151.4419914101599716, 60087.4870641206362052 -25151.4419914101599716, 60087.4870641206362052 -28251.4419914100362803, 65544.6722634464240400 -28251.4419914100362803, 64416.3645372212558868 -25151.4419914101599716))
POLYGON ((60087.4870641206362052 -28451.4419914100326423, 60087.4870641206362052 -32751.4419914099125890, 64487.4870641206289292 -32751.4419914099125890, 79187.4870641207526205 -32751.4419914099125890, 79187.4870641207526205 -28451.4419914100326423, 65687.4870641206362052 -28451.4419914100326423, 60087.4870641206362052 -28451.4419914100326423))
POLYGON ((85887.4870641205488937 -32751.4419914099125890, 85887.4870641205488937 -28451.4419914100326423, 79387.4870641207380686 -28451.4419914100326423, 79387.4870641207380686 -32751.4419914099125890, 85887.4870641205488937 -32751.4419914099125890))
POLYGON ((85887.4870641205488937 -36951.4419914102036273, 85887.4870641205488937 -32951.4419914099125890, 79287.4870641207526205 -32951.4419914099125890, 64587.4870641206362052 -32951.4419914099125890, 64587.4870641206362052 -34651.4419914099125890, 79387.4870641207380686 -34651.4419914099635207, 79387.4870641207380686 -36951.4419914102036273, 85887.4870641205488937 -36951.4419914102036273))
POLYGON ((60087.4870641206362052 -36951.4419914102036273, 79187.4870641207526205 -36951.4419914102036273, 79187.4870641207526205 -34851.4419914099635207, 64387.4870641206289292 -34851.4419914099125890, 64387.4870641206289292 -32951.4419914099125890, 60087.4870641206362052 -32951.4419914099125890, 60087.4870641206362052 -36951.4419914102036273))
```

Here's the door geometries;

```
POLYGON ((79437.4870641207380686 -36406.4419914101163158, 79437.4870641207380686 -35396.4419914101163158, 79137.4870641207380686 -35396.4419914101163158, 79137.4870641207380686 -36406.4419914101163158, 79437.4870641207380686 -36406.4419914101163158))
POLYGON ((64637.4870641206362052 -34306.4419914099344169, 64637.4870641206362052 -33296.4419914099344169, 64337.4870641206362052 -33296.4419914099344169, 64337.4870641206362052 -34306.4419914099344169, 64637.4870641206362052 -34306.4419914099344169))
POLYGON ((61982.4870641205998254 -33001.4419914099125890, 62992.4870641205998254 -33001.4419914099125890, 62992.4870641205998254 -32701.4419914099125890, 61982.4870641205998254 -32701.4419914099125890, 61982.4870641205998254 -33001.4419914099125890))
POLYGON ((79137.4870641207526205 -31346.4419914098834852, 79137.4870641207526205 -32356.4419914098834852, 79437.4870641207526205 -32356.4419914098834852, 79437.4870641207526205 -31346.4419914098834852, 79137.4870641207526205 -31346.4419914098834852))
POLYGON ((64793.2278058871524991 -26333.0555322997970507, 65138.6681506460663513 -27282.1450792935502250, 65420.5759368818398798 -27179.5390362958569312, 65075.1355921229260275 -26230.4494893020892050, 64793.2278058871524991 -26333.0555322997970507))
POLYGON ((74382.4870641207235167 -28501.4419914100362803, 75392.4870641207235167 -28501.4419914100362803, 75392.4870641207235167 -28201.4419914100362803, 74382.4870641207235167 -28201.4419914100362803, 74382.4870641207235167 -28501.4419914100362803))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to replicate your error but for me the behaviour was as expect, see below. Are you able to share the polygon data, or create a reproducible example?

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import shapely as shp

## I've created two shp layers of 2 polygons each:
rooms = gpd.read_file(path_1)
doors = gpd.read_file(path_2)
ax = plt.subplot(111)

rooms.plot(facecolor='y', ax=ax)
doors.plot(facecolor='g', ax=ax)
ax.axis('off');
```

[image: Before unary union]

Then performing unary union:

```
un_rm = shp.ops.unary_union(rooms.geometry)
un_dr = shp.ops.unary_union(doors.geometry)
un = shp.ops.unary_union([un_rm, un_dr])

df_joint = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': [un]})
df_joint.plot()
plt.axis('off');
```

[image: After unary union]

Note that I get the same result if I convert the DFs to multipolygons first, before performing unary union.

Comment: I added the geometries to the original question. I'm starting to think I need to somehow identify the "line joints" and split them maybe?

Comment: What version of `python`, `geopandas` and `shapely` did you use?

Comment: Tried on python 3.7.4, shapely 2.0.0, GEOS 3.11. Also tried Shapely 1.8.4. Tried on python 3.9 and also 3.10 with the same combination of Shapely.

Comment: I (also) used python 3.7.13, shapely 1.8.4, geopandas 0.10.2, so that's probably not the issue. Thanks for adding the geometries, but their formatting doesn't work for copy-pasting them into python (because of whitespaces). Is the issue still open?

Comment: it can be closed down. The geometries were not being removed, they were being added as interiors (holes).